# Scaling a rectangle based on one axis alone

Tags: algorithm, math

What is an efficient way to scale a rectangle (height/width) so that the width is as close as possible to X (without going over) while maintaining aspect ratio?

Comment: multiply by a fraction of the aspect ratio...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider `height/width` to be the aspect ratio - you want to increase width so width=X:

Just set `height/width = newHeight/X`, plug in your value for X and solve for `newHeight`:

```
(height/width)*X = newHeight
```

Depending on whether you need X or newHeight to be an integer, just round as necessary (either up or down depending on your restrictions).